# How to contribute to the Android API guide?

Tags: android

How to correct errors in source examples, wording, etc. on the [Android API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

I found the code repository but I did not find the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contribute to AOSP - Android Open Source Project. The process details here: http://source.android.com/source/contributing.html

The API guide sources location is **$ANDROID_ROOT/frameworks/base/docs/html/guide**

You can browse it online: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.2_r1/docs/html/

Comment: His question is about the contribution to the API guide and API documents, not the contribution to the AOSP!

Comment: Exactly. The API documentation part of the project and can be contributed in a similar way as a source code. The API location is *<aroot>/frameworks/base/docs/html/guide*

Comment: Paresh's objection was completely true but after Robert's clarification this answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the documentation on Google's web page (expect pure Javadoc originating from classes within AOSP) is neither part of AOSP nor open source at all.
My best tip would be to contact Google through one of the forums, e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-platform